# I am trying to change all the column names of the data whose class is tbl_spark

Tags: r, sparklyr

Here is the code:

```
    library(sparklyr)
    sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", config = list())
    iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris, overwrite = T)
    newColList <- c("a", "b" , "c" , "d" , " e")
    colnames(iris_tbl) <- newColList
```

Error:

> Error in colnames<- ( tmp, value = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "
>   e")) :    'dimnames' applied to non-array

Answer (score 0):

`names(iris_tbl) <- newColList` works but I think a better answer would utilize `%>%` and `dplyr::rename`

Comment: names(iris_tbl) <- newColList is throwing error: Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'e' given input columns: [b, d,  e, a, c];
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:60)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:57)

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching around for this all day. Right now my best solution is to create a custom function that goes direct to the Spark API:

```
sdf_write_colnames <- function(in_tbl, new_names) {

  sdf_name <- as.character(in_tbl$ops$x)

  in_tbl %>%
    spark_dataframe() %>%
    invoke("toDF", as.list(new_names)) %>%
    sdf_register(name = sdf_name)
}

iris_tbl <- sdf_write_colnames(iris_tbl, c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))

head(iris_tbl)
```

With a bit of effort it could be made to work more like `colnames() <-`

Comment: I'll leave this up in case it's of use, but I've had a few problems with this. Not sure all the registering should be necessary.